# React Native/Rails App: trying to send data from an API to a postgres db onPress

Tags: ruby-on-rails, react-native, state

I have an app that locates and displays brunch restaurants in React Native/Rails. The data comes from Yelp API and renders fine, i used a fetch route to the API via my Rails backend. I want users to be able to click the "Fav?" button under a specific restaurant and send only that data to my postgres db in my rails app.

I am unsure of how to do this as my fetch post route to the db is connecting, but it's receiving empty strings. I tried setting the state in the top of the function, but it isn't working.

here is what my function looks like currently:

```
async savetoFavorites(e) {
  this.setState({
  name: e.target.name,
  image: e.target.image_url,
  address: e.target.location.city,
  phone: e.target.phone
})
try {
  let response = await fetch('http://myURL', {
                          method: 'POST',
                          headers: {
                            'Accept': 'application/json',
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                          },
                          body: JSON.stringify({
                            favorite:{
                              name: this.state.name,
                              image: this.state.image,
                              address: this.state.address,
                              phone: this.state.phone
                            }
                          })
                        });
                        let res = await response.text();
                        if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {

                          const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
                          navigate('Profile', {favorites: response});
                          } else {

                            let error = res;
                            throw error;
                          }
                        }  catch(errors) {
                        }
                      }
```

Comment: You should setState once you have a successful response. Your call to setState may be causing a rerender and causing an empty response.

Comment: So I should set the state at the end of the function? How would i format that? would I put it before the navigation?

Comment: could you explain your code a bit? What happens once a successful response comes back? you simply navigate away to the profile page? If you navigate away why even update state since it will be lost unless you're using redux or something similar to manage application state? Do you end up passing the state to the profile view?

Comment: I want the user to click the fav button, and have that add the selected restaurant to their favorites page, and then take them to where it will appear (the profile page is where the favorites are to be displayed)

Comment: Ah, so what you should do is upon click, hit your api, save their favorite, then respond back with the favorites you just saved, and pass that json object as a prop to profile.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the state after you have a successful response. Maybe your call to setState is causing a re-render and causing an empty response.

```
async savetoFavorites(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  try {
    let response = await fetch('http://myURL', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        favorite: {
          name: e.target.name,
          image: e.target.image_url,
          address: e.target.location.city,
          phone: e.target.phone
        }
      })
    });
    let res = await response.text();
    if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
      this.setState({
        name: res.name,
        image: res.image,
        address: res.address,
        phone: res.phone
      })
      const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
      navigate('Profile', { favorites: res});
    } else {
      let error = res;
      throw error;
    }
  } catch (errors) {}
}
```